# How can I access contacts list in Nokia mobiles using Qt Application?

Tags: qt

I want to make a program using Qt that can access the contacts list of Nokia mobiles.
I mean by accessing changing the contacts telephone numbers "not viewing them only".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0-beta/qcontactmanagerengine.html. Maybe it will help you.

And learn about Qt Mobility of course.